# How to disable Bootstrap Collapse's API click event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter's Bootstrap 'Collapse' plugin ([documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse)) in a project that I am working on. I didn't really like how each parent element has to be clicked on in order for the collapsible items to toggle, so I wrote my own script to show and hide the collapsible items on hover instead of on click.

Here's the script code:

```
$(function spark_item_hover() {
    $(this).on('mouseenter.collapse.data-api', '[data-toggle=collapse]', function() {
        var $this = $(this), target = $this.attr('data-target')
        , option = $(target).data('collapse') ? 'show' : $this.data()
        $(target).collapse();
        $(target).show('true');
    })
    $(this).on('mouseleave.collapse.data-api', '[data-toggle=collapse]', function() {
        var $this = $(this), target = $this.attr('data-target')
        , option = $(target).data('collapse') ? 'hide' : $this.data()
        $(target).hide('true');
    })   
})
```

And here's how I call the script in HTML (with the irrelevant stuff removed):

```
<li class="spark-item" onhover="spark_item_hover()" data-target="#context155" data-toggle="collapse">
    <div class="span11">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div id="context155" class="collapse" style="height: auto; display: none;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

This basically does what I want it to do: it would show the collapsed item when I hover over it, and hide it when I move away. The only problem is, the click event defined in the API (bottom of [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js)) is still being used; when I click on the parent element, it still toggles the collapsible item. I was wondering if there's a way to disable the click toggle from the API? I still want to be able to click inside the element (because it contain links to other pages); I just don't want it to toggle the collapsible item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use another toggle token : `[data-toggle=hovercollapse]`. That way the plugin will not be enabled.